# How to call named ranges from an array in a for loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I created an array with named ranges in it.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
Sub Macro()
    ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Dim fruits As Variant
    fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut")

    For i = 1 To Length(fruits)

     Cells(5, i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range(fruits.Cells(i))(1)

    Next i
    End Sub
```

I'd like to call these named ranges from an array in a for loop. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

I'd like to display the values of the named ranges, let's say, in the 5th row.

Answer (score 1):

1-D arrays are zero-based by default, not one-based.

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim fruits As Variant

    fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut")

    For i = lbound(fruits) to ubound(fruits)
        Cells(5, i + 1) = Range(fruits(i))(1)
        'maybe this
        'Cells(5, i + 1) = Range(fruits(i)).cells(1, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're super, @Jeeped! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Array can be parsed to a range with one line:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim fruits As Variant
    Cells.Clear
    fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut")

    Range("A1:C1").Value2 = fruits
    Range("A5:A7").Value2 = Application.Transpose(fruits)

End Sub
```

[image]

---

Or even "fancier", with non hard-coded ranges:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim fruits As Variant
    Cells.Clear
    fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut")

    Dim fc As Range
    Set fc = Range("E5")

    Range(fc, fc.Offset(ColumnOffset:=UBound(fruits))) = fruits
    Range(fc, fc.Offset(UBound(fruits))) = Application.Transpose(fruits)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @Zac - w/o fancy stuff there is no fun.